# Where to get “UTF-8” string literal in Java annotations? (StandardCharset.UTF_8.name() won't work there)

Tags: java, character-encoding, annotations

While StandardCharset.UTF_8 is fine if you need a Charset, and StandardCharset.UTF_8.name() is fine if you need the String constant for that charset in regular java code, we're out of luck with an official constant for "UTF-8" in annotation attributes, since calling .name() isn't constant enough for annotations.

Java itself doesn't contain them, and org.apache.commons.lang3.CharEncoding.UTF_8 (or actually the CharEncoding class itself) is marked @deprecated and marked for removal in a future release.

Is there a best practise for specifying "UTF-8" other than literally in annotation attributes?

```java
import feign.Headers;
import feign.RequestLine;

public interface MyInterface {
    @RequestLine("GET /foo/bar")
    @Headers("Accept: application/xml", 
             "Accept-Charset: " + StandardCharset.UTF_8.name())
    String getData();
}
```

The above code doesn't compile because UTF_8.name() is not constant. Note that feign's @Headers attribute is just an example.

Comment: Create a constant for it yourself?

Comment: Guava probably still has it, if you happen to be using that.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Guava appears to have the [`Charsets`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Charsets.html) class, but its constants are instances of `java.nio.charset.Charset`, which runs into the same problem as when trying to use `StandardCharsets`.

Comment: @user7294900 as Slaw said, that question suggests StandardCharset.UTF_8, plus calling .name(), but for annotation arguments that doesn't work, and other common constants (multiple ones available in apache libraries) seem to be @ deprecated nowadays due to StandardCharset.

Comment: @UlrichGrepel I think your best, and simplest, option is to create the constant yourself, as Sweeper suggested. Pulling in an entire library just for this is overkill anyway.

Comment: @Slaw - if I had to pull in a library just for that one constant you'd be right. But e.g. feign itself uses the apache http stuff under the covers, and other libraries might be required in other places of the application, so a "best practise" constant might already be present.

A good candidate would be org.apache.commons.lang3.CharEncoding.UTF_8, but as I said the guys from there deprecated the constant due to its existence in enhanced (but not annotation friendly) way in Java itself.

Comment: It would be nice if the StandardCharsets class would itself use a public static final String constant instead of just a constructor argument for the actual encoding Strings.